# Live price updates in R-Bloomberg price subcriptions

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am using the RBloomberg library for live and historical price data, but I would like to know if it is possible for a variable to update its live pricing continuously. Right now:

```
> library(RBloomberg)
Loading required package: rJava
> conn <- blpConnect()
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25) 
rJava Version 0.8-8 
RBloomberg Version 0.4-148 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Looking for most recent blpapi3.jar file...
Adding C:\blp\API\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.4.1.3\lib\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
Bloomberg API Version 3.4.1.3 
> bdp(conn, "EURUSD Curncy", "Last Price")
              Last Price
EURUSD Curncy     1.4575
```

So as you can see I can get the EURUSD exchange rate easily. But how can I make a variable *subscribe* to the EURUSD Curncy Last_price so that the variable updates itself in real time for the current value, rather than always re-running bdp(conn, "EURUSD Curncy", "last price")? Could I do something like this?

```
> eurusd <- bdp(conn, "EURUSD Curncy", "Last Price")
> eurusd
              Last Price
EURUSD Curncy     1.4575
```

so that whenever I type eurusd I get the *latest* exchange rate and not the one from when I initialised the variable? Right now this does not seem to work (just has the same value in it all the time even after the exchange rate has changed).

```
> eurusd
              Last Price
EURUSD Curncy     1.4575
> eurusd
              Last Price
EURUSD Curncy     1.4575
> eurusd <- bdp(conn, "EURUSD Curncy", "Last Price")
> eurusd
              Last Price
EURUSD Curncy     1.4578
>
```

Basically, can R do what Excel does, which is to have a cell which always has the latest value of EURUSD in it, without constantly running bdp to update the variable?

Comment: I think you could just do `eurusd = function() bdp(conn, "EURUSD Curncy", "Last Price")`. This way, whenever you call `eurusd()`, you can be assured that you are getting the latest price.

Comment: Thanks Ramnath, but that doesn't seem to work. If I do this then it simply prints out "function() bdp(conn, "EURUSD Curncy", "Last Price")" if I type > eurusd

Comment: type `eurosd()` to execute the function. Without the `()`, R is letting you view the internals of the function. See [here](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~aredd/site/?q=node/44) for a quick write up on it.

Comment: Cool, that works. Thanks. Now here is another related question. Does this method re-subscribe to the EURUSD ticker every time I run eurusd()? Because that would use up a lot of my daily/monthly Bloomberg data allowance (the terminal has a limit on how many subscriptions you can do per day), especially if I am updating it very frequently. In Excel (or Python) once you're subscribed it uses 1 of your (large) daily allowance and updates continuously........

Separately, I would have liked to accept your solution as an answer but you've typed it as a comment, preventing me from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually BB will make you get a Data License if you keep hitting the item request limits which they do monitor. Unfortunately the Data License is only static data. If you really want more then you have to go with BPIPE.

Comment: precisely. That's why I plan to use Python for the data subscriptions. Two related questions:
1) How do I find out how close I am to my limit?
2) What's BPIPE?